# Producto cartesiano con select random mysql

Tags: mysql

He conseguido hacer la consulta:

```
select * from (select x from a ORDER BY rand() limit 15) as a, (select x2 from b) as b
```

La salida es:

1  |  a
1  |  b
1  |  c
3  |  a
3  |  b
3  |  c
2  |  a
2  |  b
2  |  c

Pero lo que necesito es que realmente los registros de la tabla **a** sean aleatorios para cada registro de **b**, puede haber algun repetido pero no todos.

A ver si alguien tiene alguna idea.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar lo que significa: *que realmente los registros de la tabla a sean aleatorios para cada registro de b*  poniendo algún ejemplo preferiblemente?

Comment: A lo de que sean realmente aleatorios, me refería que la salida sea algo como:
1  |  a,
1  |  c,
2  |  b,
2  |  a,
3  |  c,
4  |  b. La idea es que los 15 registros de la tabla **a** sean diferentes para cada registro de **b** (aunque puede haber algun repetido). No sé si me explico bien.

Answer (score 0):

No me quedó muy claro lo que quieres lograr, pero tal vez esto sea lo que buscas:

```
SELECT a.x AS a, b.x2 AS b FROM a INNER JOIN b ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: Gracias @RockoDev por tu respuesta pero me ha funcionado parcialmente. He conseguido que los registros de ambas tablas queden mezclados pero el problema es que solo me arroja 15 registros en total. Lo que busco es que todos los registros de **b**(sea 1 o 20.000) tengan 15 registros de **a**(de todos los que tiene **a** pero solo cogiendo 15 aleatorios para cada registro de **b**) pero al azar, que no todos los de **b** tengan los mismos de **a**.